# NSURLSession code is working fine on simulator but It's not working on device.

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I have implement server downloading in iOS using `NSURLSession`, its working fine on simulator but on device some problem is occurred and download will finished with error `1004`, I think its time bound problem. some time data will downloaded successfully, please help in that.

Comment: please show your code and the error you are receiving. Its not possible to help you otherwise

Answer (score 0):

1004 means "cannot connect to host". Did you use something like localhost? Or you are referring to a host that is locally available though LAN but not for the device though GSM (cellular) or WLAN.

In that case I suggest putting up a WLAN access point or using your local machines' WLAN port as access point (infrastructure mode, adhoc may do as well if the server is on that machine).

BTW, WLAN means Wireless LAN or WiFi.